# Get fractional part of real in QF_UFNRA

Tags: z3, smt, cvc4

Using smtlib I would like to make something like modulo using QF_UFNRA. This disables me from using mod, to_int, to_real an such things.

In the end I want to get the fractional part of z in the following code:

```
(set-logic QF_UFNRA)

(declare-fun z () Real)
(declare-fun z1 () Real)
(define-fun zval_1 ((x Real)) Real
         x
)
(declare-fun zval (Real) Real)

(assert (= z 1.5));
(assert (=> (and (<= 0.0 z) (< z 1.0)) (= (zval z) (zval_1 z))))
(assert (=> (>= z 1.0) (= (zval z) (zval (- z 1.0)))))
(assert (= z1 (zval z)))
```

Of course, as I am asking this question here, implies, that it didn't work out.

Has anybody got an idea how to get the fractional part of z into z1 using logic QF_UFNRA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great question. Unfortunately, what you want to do is ***not*** possible in general if you restrict yourself to `QF_UFNRA`.

If you could encode such functionality, then you can decide arbitrary Diophantine equations. You would simply cast a given Diophantine equation over reals, compute the "fraction" of the real solution with this alleged method, and assert that the fraction is `0`. Since reals are decidable, this would give you a decision procedure for Diophantine equations, accomplishing the impossible. (This is known as Hilbert's 10th problem.)

So, as innocent as the task looks, it is actually not doable. But that doesn't mean you cannot encode this with some extensions, and possibly have the solver successfully decide instances of it.

### If you allow quantifiers and recursive functions

If you allow yourself quantifiers and recursive-functions, then you can write:

```
(set-logic UFNRA)

(define-fun-rec frac ((x Real)) Real (ite (< x 1) x (frac (- x 1))))

(declare-fun res () Real)
(assert (= (frac 1.5) res))

(check-sat)
(get-value (res))
```

To which z3 responds:

```
sat
((res (/ 1.0 2.0)))
```

Note that we used the `UFNRA` logic allowing quantification, which is required here implicitly due to the use of the `define-fun-rec` construct. (See the SMTLib manual for details.) This is essentially what you tried to encode in your question, but instead using the recursive-function-definition facilities instead of implicit encoding. There are several caveats in using recursive functions in SMTLib however: In particular, you can write functions that render your system inconsistent rather easily. See Section 4.2.3 of http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.5-draft.pdf for details.

### If you can use QF_UFNIRA

If you move to `QF_UFNIRA`, i.e., allow mixing reals and integers, the encoding is easy:

```
(set-logic QF_UFNIRA)

(declare-fun z  () Real)
(declare-fun zF () Real)
(declare-fun zI () Int)

(assert (= z (+ zF zI)))
(assert (<= 0 zF))
(assert (< zF 1))

(assert (= z 1.5))
(check-sat)
(get-value (zF zI))
```

z3 responds:

```
sat
((zF (/ 1.0 2.0))
 (zI 1))
```

(You might have to be careful about the computation of `zI` when `z < 0`, but the idea is the same.)

Note that just because the encoding is easy doesn't mean z3 will always be able to answer the query successfully. Due to mixing of `Real`'s and `Integer`'s, the problem remains undecidable as discussed before. If you have other constraints on `z`, z3 might very well respond `unknown` to this encoding. In this particular case, it happens to be simple enough so z3 is able to find a model.

### If you have `sin` and `pi`:

This is more of a thought experiment than a real alternative. If SMTLib allowed for `sin` and `pi`, then you can check whether `sin (zI * pi)` is `0`, for a suitably constrained `zI`. Any satisfying model to this query would ensure that `zI` is integer. You can then use this value to extract the fractional part by subtracting `zI` from `z`.

But this is futile as SMTLib neither allows for `sin` nor `pi`. And for good reason: Decidability would be lost. Having said that, maybe some brave soul can design a logic that supported `sin`, `pi`, etc., and successfully answered your query correctly, while returning `unknown` when the problem becomes too hard for the solver. This is already the case for nonlinear arithmetic and the `QF_UFNIRA` fragment: The solver may give up in general, but the heuristics it employs might solve problems of practical interest.

### Restriction to Rationals

As a theoretical aside, it turns out that if you restrict yourself to rationals only (instead of actual reals) then you can indeed write a first-order formula to recognize integers. The encoding is not for the faint of heart, however: http://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/ae.pdf. Furthermore, since the encoding involves quantifiers, it's probably quite unlikely that SMT solvers will do well with a formulation based on this idea.

[Incidentally, I should extend thanks to my work colleagues; this question made for a great lunch-time conversation!]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually, my problem was (and is) to approximate sin (and other trigonometrical functions) as SMT problem. For this to be possible I wanted to compute the incoming variable to be 0 <= x < 2pi. I will have to look, if I can mix with quantifiers or the other mentioned theories without leaving the solvable space.

Comment: Cool. You should checkout `dReal`: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sicung/papers/dReal.pdf. I haven't used it myself personally, but it claims to support trigonometric functions using the notion of δ-satisfiability. (The problem is undecidable in general, but satisfiability can be checked if you allow for certain precision loss.)

Comment: Also: If you can move to a theorem proving environment, MetiTarski is a powerful tool that supports transcendentals: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/papers/Arith/

Comment: I tried dReal3. Very nice, but lacks models and UNSAT-cores. Just to let you know.