# Floor and Ceiling Function implementation in Z3

Tags: z3, smt, z3py, floor, ceil

I have tried to implement Floor and Ceiling Function as defined in the following link

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3619044/floor-or-ceiling-function-encoding-in-first-order-logic/3619320#3619320

But Z3 query returning counterexample.

Floor Function

```
_X=Real('_X')
_Y=Int('_Y')
_W=Int('_W')
_n=Int('_n')
_Floor=Function('_Floor',RealSort(),IntSort())
..
_s.add(_X>=0)
_s.add(_Y>=0)
_s.add(Implies(_Floor(_X)==_Y,And(Or(_Y==_X,_Y<_X),ForAll(_W,Implies(And(_W>=0,_W<_X),And(_W ==_Y,_W<_Y))))))
_s.add(Implies(And(Or(_Y==_X,_Y<_X),ForAll(_W,Implies(And(_W>=0,_W<_X),And(_W==_Y,_W<_Y))),_Floor(_X)==_Y))
_s.add(Not(_Floor(0.5)==0))
```

Expected Result - Unsat

Actual Result - Sat

Ceiling Function

```
_X=Real('_X')
_Y=Int('_Y')
_W=Int('_W')
_Ceiling=Function('_Ceiling',RealSort(),IntSort())
..
..
_s.add(_X>=0)
_s.add(_Y>=0)
_s.add(Implies(_Ceiling(_X)==_Y,And(Or(_Y==_X,_Y<_X),ForAll(_W,Implies(And(_W>=0,_W<_X),And(_W ==_Y,_Y<_W))))))
_s.add(Implies(And(Or(_Y==_X,_Y<_X),ForAll(_W,Implies(And(_W>=0,_W<_X),And(_W==_Y,_Y<_W)))),_Ceiling(_X)==_Y))
_s.add(Not(_Ceilng(0.5)==1))
```

Expected Result - Unsat

Actual Result - Sat

Comment: JDart is using Z3 and is able to handle `ceil` function - https://github.com/psycopaths/jdart/blob/b6c238bcdf0383b067331358efb09f728fdeb3b9/src/peers/gov/nasa/jpf/jdart/peers/JPF_java_lang_Math.java#L263

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Your encoding doesn't load to z3, it gives a syntax error even after eliminating the '..', as your call to `Implies` needs an extra argument. But I'll ignore all that.]

The short answer is, you can't really do this sort of thing in an SMT-Solver. If you could, then you can solve arbitrary Diophantine equations. Simply cast it in terms of Reals, solve it (there is a decision procedure for Reals), and then add the extra constraint that the result is an integer by saying `Floor(solution) = solution`. So, by this argument, you can see that modeling such functions will be beyond the capabilities of an SMT solver.

See this answer for details: [Get fractional part of real in QF_UFNRA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133675/get-fractional-part-of-real-in-qf-ufnra/42147549#42147549)

Having said that, this does *not* mean you cannot code this up in Z3. It just means that it will be more or less useless. Here's how I would go about it:

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

Floor = Function('Floor',RealSort(),IntSort())

r = Real('R')
f = Int('f')
s.add(ForAll([r, f], Implies(And(f <= r, r < f+1), Floor(r) == f)))
```

Now, if I do this:

```py
s.add(Not(Floor(0.5) == 0))
print(s.check())
```

you'll get `unsat`, which is correct. If you do this instead:

```py
s.add(Not(Floor(0.5) == 1))
print(s.check())
```

you'll see that z3 simply loops forever. To make this usefull, you'd want the following to work as well:

```py
test = Real('test')
s.add(test == 2.4)
result = Int('result')
s.add(Floor(test) == result)
print(s.check())
```

but again, you'll see that z3 simply loops forever.

So, bottom line: Yes, you can model such constructs, and z3 will correctly answer the simplest of queries. But with anything interesting, it'll simply loop forever. (Essentially whenever you'd expect `sat` and most of the `unsat` scenarios unless they can be constant-folded away, I'd expect z3 to simply loop.) And there's a very good reason for that, as I mentioned: Such theories are just not decidable and fall well out of the range of what an SMT solver can do.

If you are interested in modeling such functions, your best bet is to use a more traditional theorem prover, like Isabelle, Coq, ACL2, HOL, HOL-Light, amongst others. They are much more suited for working on these sorts of problems. And also, give a read to [Get fractional part of real in QF_UFNRA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133675/get-fractional-part-of-real-in-qf-ufnra/42147549#42147549) as it goes into some of the other details of how you can go about modeling such functions using non-linear real arithmetic.